# How to keep the navbar fixed to top in big screens only using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically I want my menu to activate the fixed class when the when I scroll down 150 pixels and the width of the screen is bigger than 850 pixels.

I used this code but the menu  is still being fixed to the top in small screens(less than 850px):

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 850) {
            var num = 150;
//            $('nav#site-navigation').addClass('fixed');
                $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
                        $('nav#site-navigation').addClass('fixed');
                        }
                     else {                    
                        $('nav#site-navigation').removeClass('fixed');
                    }
                });
            }

        else{
            $('nav#site-navigation').removeClass('fixed');
        }
```

Here my css if needed:

```
.fixed {
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: auto !important;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

How can I put the navbar fixed to the top only when the screen is bigger than 850?

Comment: by *small screens* you mean mobile devices?

Comment: Mean all devices which the width of the screen is no bigger than 850 pixels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a media query to that css class:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 850px){
    .fixed {
        top: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: auto !important;
        z-index: 9999;
        position:fixed !important;
    } 
}
```

Comment: and remove `if ($(window).width() > 850) {` from your `javascript` code

Comment: @spirit.Yes. I just realized that I had to do that as well.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to use CSS @media like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    .fixed {
        position: static !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically that yes. I used initial position though.

Comment: Will get to fix that.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used this based on @holtc idea and it works

```
@media (max-width: 850px){    
    nav#site-navigation.fixed {
         position: initial !important;
    }    
}
```